# Computing Phase Difference Between Two Channels from SDR

Tags: fourier-transform, phase, cross-correlation, software-defined-radio

I'm trying to compute the phase difference between two channels of a software-defined radio. I'm providing code for two different methods that I'm trying below. In both cases, I'm transmitting a pure tone from a radio placed a few meters away from both antennas. I expect that the phase difference should remain relatively stable between the two channels (and that I receive a similar value using both methods), but I've found that it varies widely over time.

In the first method I'm computing a cross-correlation between the two channels, measuring the difference in samples between the two peaks of this correlation, and then using that to calculate phase shift.

In the second method, I'm computing the cross spectral density of the two signals, and averaging the angle between the complex values in the band that the signal occupies to calculate phase shift.

`fsamp` is the number of complex samples per second coming from each channel, and `nsamp` is the total number of complex samples collected from each channel. `samps` is an `nsamp X 2` matrix of complex floating-point samples from the software-defined radio. The code I'm providing is in Python, and all the signal processing functions are from scipy.signal, but I expect that it doesn't matter. Is there something wrong with either approach?

**Approach 1: Cross-Correlation**

```
window = get_window("hamming", nsamp)
fft0 = fft(samps[:,0]*window)
fft1 = fft(samps[:,1]*window)
fft0 = fftshift(fft0)
fft1 = fftshift(fft1)

max0 = np.argmax(np.abs(fft0))
max1 = np.argmax(np.abs(fft0))
if max0 != max1:
    print("WARN: Channel frequencies not the same!")

center_diff = (nsamp/2)-max0
freq_res = fsamp/nsamp
freq_hz = center_diff*freq_res

res = correlate(samps[:,0],samps[:,1])
max_idx = np.argmax(res)

# With no phase shift, the max idx should be at nsamp
diff = max_idx-nsamp
diff_time = diff/fsamp
diff_phase = (diff_time/(1/freq_hz))*360
diff_phase = (diff_phase+360)%180
print(diff_phase)
```

**Approach 2: CSD**

```
f, P = csd(samps[:,0], samps[:,1], fsamp)
P = fftshift(P)
f = fftshift(f)
angle = np.angle(P, deg=False)

shifted_center = signal_center - fcenter
min_freq = shifted_center - signal_bwidth/2
max_freq = shifted_center + signal_bwidth/2
idxs = np.where(np.logical_and(f>=min_freq, f<=max_freq))

sig_angle = np.mean(angle[idxs])
print(sig_angle)
```

Comment: "I expect that the phase difference should remain relatively stable between the two channel": *remain the same* among which realizations/experiments/?

Comment: Shouldn’t `max1` be the peak of `fft1` not `fft0` ?